# What is the difference between require and be required?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

*We do not require your service.*

*We are not required your service.*

To me, both sentences convey the same meaning. Does it? Or is there any subtle difference?

Comment: 'We are not required your service' is not correct English.

Comment: Ahh, Your countrymen use it on and off. Other day I was talking with an English and He used exactly the sentence.

Comment: People make mistakes.

Comment: I doubt that _an English person_ would have said that. If _you_ don't require a service, it's the _service_ that is not required.

Comment: Or possibly you misheard the sentence. .

Comment: @user66974 I did not. I mentioned it before. I hear this wrong expression on and off. To be honest I hear many expressions that sound wrong. But they say what a native says is grammar.

Comment: @KateBunting The other day a guy from Birmingham said, " You can find someone who is far more better than me." It sounded really cool. It still sounds cool now.

Comment: Native speakers certainly do not always use correct grammar, either because they don't know any better, because they are consciously using informal language, or because they start to say something and change their mind mid-sentence.

Comment: @ghost,  may I politely recommend humility? You are an English learner, and while native speakers make mistakes all the time, English learners do too.  Mishearing is not a crime, it is difficult to catch all the words spoken by a native speaker when they are talking at speed.  It is very possible that the native speaker made a mistake, but it is also very possible that you misheard.  You can be sure though that this *is* a mistake, and learners should not try to copy mistakes!

Comment: @KateBunting - my partner has a friend who thinks that because she is a teacher, she is entitled to correct anyone and everyone. Partner and I jocularly call a number of sheep 'sheeps'. She forgot and did it with her pal, who corrected her! Now we try to talk about sheeps every time we see Miss Teacher.

Comment: @JamesK By no means, I deny my fallibility. And, speaking of humility, I am quite popular for that. I think you have not noticed, I said I had heard it several times before. I am preparing for the CPE exam and another special English assessment exam designed for the foreign service recruitment. So, learning the correct grammar is mandatory. I heard that expression again yesterday and had decided to deal with it because it always sounded wrong to me. After failing to find an explanation I ended up here. I do not have the luxury of time to point out native English speakers' mistakes.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, with a mother, 2 aunts and a cousin all teachers I was learned to speak English propper, like wot you does.

Comment: @Ghost `“because it always sounded wrong to me“` but in your question you do not say this, you asked: **“To me, both sentences convey the same meaning.”** So which is it? You knew it was wrong or you thought that they were correct and you wanted a confirmation? Do you live in an English-speaking country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are required

is a passive construction. It does not take a direct object. It means the same as "Someone  requires us"

This is the opposite of "We require".  In the passive form the requirement is placed **on** "us" but in the active form the requirement is placed **by** "us"

So "We are not required your service" is incorrect grammar and fairly meaningless. It could only be spoken in error, though it is an unlikely error for a native speaker to make.  Most likely you misheard.

It may be an error for "We are not required to service".  This is a catetative construction with the infinitive forming a chain of two verbs. But the sense here is passive and the meaning is the opposite to the first example.

The first option "We do not require your service" is normal and correct.

Comment: 'the formal and formulaic "We are not required of your service".' - I have _never, ever_ seen or heard anything like that.

Comment: It sounds "Jeevesish" to me.